# How to change the values in some columns which meet some requirements in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,1,0,5],
             [2,2,9,7],
             [3,5,5,7],
             [4,8,8,9],
             [5,7,3,6],
             [6,8,1,9]])
```

Now, I would like to change the values of the second to fourth columns if the value of the third column is larger than 4 into -1 and remove all of them at the bottom of the array.

The result might be like this:

```
b = np.array([[1,1,0,5],            
         [5,7,3,6],
         [6,8,1,9],
         [2,-1,-1,-1],
         [3,-1,-1,-1],
         [4,-1,-1,-1]])
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
# find the rows that need to be updated
idx2update = a[:,2] > 4

# update rows with -1
a[idx2update, 1:] = -1

# make a new array with correct order
np.concatenate([a[~idx2update], a[idx2update]])

#[[ 1  1  0  5]
# [ 5  7  3  6]
# [ 6  8  1  9]
# [ 2 -1 -1 -1]
# [ 3 -1 -1 -1]
# [ 4 -1 -1 -1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do that?

- Make a boolean array for your condition: `third column is larger than 4`

  - it should look like this for your example `[False,True,True,True,False,False]`
- Use that on the left-hand-side of an assignment to filter the rows:

  ```
  a[boolean_array, 1:] = -1
  ```
- using the boolean array to select rows -  concatenate rows that don't meet the condition with those that do.

  ```
  np.concatenate(a[~boolean_array], a[boolean_array])
  ```

---

[Boolean or “mask” index arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)

[Assignment vs referencing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#assignment-vs-referencing)